# For loop with file names

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have several files (tables) named as: *institute*`_`*model*`_`*scenario*`_`*river*`.txt`

(*institute*, *model*, *scenario*, and *river* are variables.) I would like to create a `for` loop that will identify each files that have the same *institute* name and at the same time the same *scenario* name, in order to append the results of each different *model* in the same output file, using the following command:

```
paste filename1.txt filename2.txt > output_file.txt
```

I know how to create a `for` loop over different folder but not over file names. Anyone has an idea?

As a minimal example, the filenames could be as follow:

```
wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_ipsl_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_hadgem_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_miroc_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
```

Then, I would like to append the following files together:

```
wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt with
wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt

matsiro_ipsl_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt with
matsiro_hadgem_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt

matsiro_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt with
matsiro_miroc_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
```

Comment: Do you know the possible values of `institute`, `model` and `scenario`? Do you need to parse them from the file names?

Comment: @ terdon - Yes I do know the possible values, that´s why I would like to implement a kind of `for` loop over the values I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are all in the same dir, you can:

```
ls |
awk -F_ '{ i=$1; m=$2; s=$3; f[i"_"s] = f[i"_"s] " " $0 }
         END{ for(insc in f)
                printf "paste%s >out_%s.txt\n",f[insc],insc
         }'
```

which splits the filename on "_" (`-F_`), sets the variables i,m,s
to the first 3 parts of the filename (institute,model,scenario),
and accumulates in array f the filename. The array is indexed
only by the institute and scenario, so all the models are concatenated
(m isn't used). The final END prints the f array, and uses the index (institute_scenario) as the
name for the output file. With your examples this produces

```
paste wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt >out_wbm_rcp8p5.txt
paste matsiro_hadgem_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt matsiro_ipsl_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt >out_matsiro_rcp4p5.txt
paste matsiro_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt matsiro_miroc_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt >out_matsiro_rcp8p5.txt
```

You then need to pipe this into the shell to have it executed. Add `| sh` to the last line above to do this.

---

To remove some columns from the input files, you need to alter the awk line
that is collecting all the input filenames.  In the 1st awk line:

```
{ i=$1; m=$2; s=$3; f[i"_"s] = f[i"_"s] " " $0 }
```

the filename is the "$0". For example, if you change this line into:

```
{ i=$1; m=$2; s=$3; f[i"_"s] = f[i"_"s] sprintf(" <(cut -f4 %s)",$0) }
```

then you will get the example output:

```
paste <(cut -f4 wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt) <(cut -f4 wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt) >out_wbm_rcp8p5.txt
```

but if you want to cut only the 2nd filename, it is a bit more complicated and
you need this instead:

```
{ i=$1; m=$2; s=$3; 
  if(f[i"_"s]=="")add = $0; else add = sprintf("<(cut -f4 %s)",$0);
  f[i"_"s] = f[i"_"s] " " add }
```

so you will get

```
paste wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt <(cut -f4 wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt) >out_wbm_rcp8p5.txt
```

If `sh` does not understand the syntax `<(cut ...)` then replace it by `bash`.

Comment: @ meuh - Is there a way to define i, m, s possible variables, like in a for loop?

Comment: the script goes through the variables automatically. I added the output for your examples.

Comment: @ meuh - Indeed it seems to produce the desired output. But I might sound stupid but I always have some syntax error while try to actually run the code by removing the fprintf. Could you provide me the right syntax with the fprintf removed please?

Comment: the `printf` is part of the `for` loop of the line above. if you remove it there will be no output. Sorry, I didn't say: you need to pipe the output into `sh` to actually do the `paste` commands. The script just generates the commands, but doesn't execute them. So add `|sh` to the last line to actually create the output files.

Comment: @ meuh - And I want to remove the first three column of the files that are `paste` to the first one. I try to use `"paste%s <(cut -f4 %s) >out_%s.txt\n`  without success, do you have any idea why?

Comment: I updated my answer with different versions of just the first line in the awk script. You still need the rest of the script.

Comment: @ meuh - When I try to run:

    `ls |
     awk -F_ '{ i=$1; m=$2; s=$3;
               if(f[i"_"s]=="")add = $0; else add = sprintf("<(cut -f4 %s)",$0);
               f[i"_"s] = f[i"_"s] " " add }
               END{ for(insc in f)
                      printf "paste%s > out_%s.txt\n",f[insc],insc
               }' |sh`
I always get the error message `sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: your `sh` does not understand the `<()` syntax, so you need to use `|bash` instead of `|sh`.

Comment: @ meuh - I have learned a lot today!

Comment: @steve be aware that parsing `ls` is [usually a very bad idea](mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @ terdon - Great notification! Your answer works also perfectly (and I guess that the coding is more comprehensible and cleaner).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there is no difference between a `for` loop for directories and one for files. It's exactly the same thing. Remember that on *nix, [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

So, your loop would be something like this:

```
for institute in institute1 institute2 institute3
do
    for scenario in scenario1 scenario2 scenario3
    do
        paste "$institute"_*_"$scenario"* > "$institute"_"$scenario".out
    done
done
```

If you don't know the institute and scenario names, you could just run this for all files and extract them from the filenames (as long as your names don't contain whitespace):

```
for f in *; do echo "${f/_*} ${f##*_}"; done | 
    sort -u | while read ins sce; do 
        paste "$ins"_*_"$sce"* > "$ins"_"$sce".out
    done
```

Comment: @ terdon - This answer works also perfectly! 
Moreover, considering the fact that I would like to get ride of the first three column of the appended table; I have tried to add at the `paste` line `paste "$hyd_model"_*_"$scenario"* <(cut -f4 "$hyd_model"_*_"$scenario"*) > "$hyd_model"_"$scenario".txt` but it´s not working. I would like to understand why if you have any hints?

Comment: @steve how is it "not working"? Any error messages? What you describe should work so if it doesn't, it will depend on what's in your files or what filenames you have. It might be better to post a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using ls command.
Something like `ls $institute_*_$scenario_*.txt` should return all files with the same institute and scenario.

Comment: No need for `ls`, you can just do `paste $institute_*_$scenario_*.txt`.